# Problem with Iteration and Set

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, iterator, set

I have a problem with my program.

When i run the program:

```
CourseMaterial crsmPrint = new CourseMaterial();

Iterator<CourseMaterial> itPrint = trs.getAllTrainerCourseMaterial(Integer.parseInt(request.getSession().getAttribute("id").toString())).iterator();

while (itPrint.hasNext()){
   crsmPrint = itPrint.next();
   Lecture lctPrint = new Lecture();
   Iterator<Lecture> itLctPrint = trs.getAllLecture(crsmPrint.getId()).iterator();
   while(itLctPrint.hasNext()){
      lctPrint = itLctPrint.next();
      out.print("<option>"+lctPrint.getId()+"</option>");
   }
}
```

The error is:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: lesson.domain.CourseMaterial.lectures, no session or session was closed
```

There are a problem in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using ORM in your application and configured **lectures** to be loaded lazily. You can either change the config to load them eagerly or iterate the lectures in a transaction.

Comment: I would also recommend two foreach loops, because it leaves the code clean.